# CakePHP's Form Helper Input vs HTML Simple Input

Tags: cakephp, input, formhelper

I'm new to CakePHP. I would like to know what are the advantages of using CakePHP's Form Helper to add input boxes in Views over simply adding HTML inputs. Which one is better way / recommended way to use?

Comment: Simply read the book? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Form Helper in addition to using the `Security` and `CSRF Components` your form will be protected from `CSRF` and other form-related attacks.

You should definitely use the Form Helper. For more information, access this link here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html

In addition, if you use it at every instance during your learning process, you will master it quickly and it can save you time.

Comment: Thanks Andre Santiago.. It was helpful information.